# Running a .WSF script file from a C# application?

Tags: c#, wsh

I'm completely stumped. Is there any way to have a .wsf script run via a c# application (Windows forum application)?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) at all?

Comment: @Brian: Presumably he doesn't understand that he needs to "shell out" to run the script.  Perhaps you can explain it to him in an answer?

Comment: @Joel: Windows Scripting Files are executed using a Scripting Host, such as WScript or CScript.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how to use that class. I'm really new to coding.

Would I just do: Process.Start(pathOfScript) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) to call the script host:

```
string scriptFile = GetWsfFileNameWithPath();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WScript.exe", "//B //Nologo " + scriptFile);
```

For details on the command line arguments, see [TechNet's article on running scripts from the command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx).

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for the quick answers and reference links guys!

Comment: I cannot run this......Process configurProcess = Process.Start("WScript.exe", "//B //Nologo " + "{49A7D330-A7C5-4B4C-9980-84D2EE94070E}\\GPOPack.wsf");
configurProcess.WaitForExit(); but nothing happens.